# How to set an initial state with hooks when data finish to load

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I'm trying to set `full_name` as my initial state, but I'm getting undefined. I cant check this when I send the data to my `props.userDetailsFetchRequest(id, data);`, How I can set this initial state just when the data finish loading.

```
 const UserDetails = props => {
            const classes = useStyles();

            const { userDetailsLoading } = props;
            const { full_name } = props.userDetails;

            console.log('loading:', userDetailsLoading)
            console.log('full name:', full_name)

            const [name, setName] = useState(full name); <-------- I want this inicialize with
                                                                         michele sena riveira  

          function handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const { id } = props.userDetails;

            const data = {
                "full_name": name,
            }

            props.userDetailsFetchRequest(id, data); <--- I'm sending this request to my saga
    and I'm getting full_name as undefined.
        }
```

[image]

---

Saga

```
function* userDetailsEditFetchRequest({ id, data }) {
       console.log("full_name in saga:",data)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `useEffect` for this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setName(full_name)
},[full_name]
```

Now, whenever full_name changes, the effect will update your state value with whatever the prop's value is.

However it is better to just use the prop directly when you can, to eliminate any possible discrepancies